# Logistic glm: marginal predicted probabilities and log-odds coefficients support different hypotheses

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, marginal-effect

I'm running a fixed effects logistic regression in R. The model consists of a binary outcome and two binary predictors, with no interaction term. On the log-odds scale, and as an odds-ratio, the coefficient for one of the predictors (`carbf` in the mocked-up example below) indicates that the expected probability of Y=1 ("success") is different between the two levels of the factor (i.e., the effect is significant).

When I use the `effects` package to get marginal predicted probabilities, the 95% CIs for the two levels of `carbf` overlap considerably, indicating there is no evidence of a difference in the expected probability of Y=1 between the two factor levels.

When I use the `mfx` package to get average marginal effects for the coefficients (i.e., for the expected *difference* in the probability of Y=1 between the two factor levels), I do get a significant difference.

**I'm confused as to whether this discrepancy is because:**

**1) the output from the model and the `mfx` package is an expected *difference* in the probability of Y=1 between factor levels, rather than predicted probabilities for each level.**

**2) of the way the `effects` package is calculating the marginal effect.**

In an effort to determine this, I modified the source code from the `mfx` package to give me average marginal effects for each level of the `carbf` factor. The 95% CIs for these predictions *do not* overlap, indicating a significant difference. This makes me wonder why I get such different results using the `effects` package. Or is it that I'm just confused about the difference between marginal effects for coefficients and for predicted probabilities?

```
#####################################
# packages
library(effects)
library(mfx)
library(ggplot2)

# data
data(mtcars)
carsdat <- mtcars
carsdat$carb <- ifelse(carsdat$carb %in% 1:3, 0, 1)
facvars <- c("vs", "am", "carb")
carsdat[, paste0(facvars, "f")] <- lapply(carsdat[, facvars], factor)

# model
m1 <- glm(vsf ~ amf + carbf, 
    family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = carsdat)
summary(m1)


#####################################
# effects package
eff <- allEffects(m1)
plot(eff, rescale.axis = FALSE)
eff_df <- data.frame(eff[["carbf"]])
eff_df 

#   carbf   fit    se  lower upper
# 1     0 0.607 0.469 0.3808 0.795
# 2     1 0.156 0.797 0.0375 0.469


#####################################
# mfx package marginal effects (at mean)
mfx1 <-logitmfx(vsf ~ amf + carbf, data = carsdat, atmean = TRUE, robust = FALSE)
mfx1 

#         dF/dx Std. Err.     z  P>|z|
# amf1    0.217     0.197  1.10 0.2697
# carbf1 -0.450     0.155 -2.91 0.0037

# mfx package marginal effects (averaged)
mfx2 <-logitmfx(vsf ~ amf + carbf, data = carsdat, atmean = FALSE, robust = FALSE)
mfx2

#         dF/dx Std. Err.     z  P>|z|
# amf1    0.177     0.158  1.12 0.2623
# carbf1 -0.436     0.150 -2.90 0.0037


#####################################
# mfx source code
fit <- m1
x1 = model.matrix(fit)  
be = as.matrix(na.omit(coef(fit)))
k1 = length(na.omit(coef(fit)))
fxb = mean(plogis(x1 %*% be)*(1-plogis(x1 %*% be))) 
vcv = vcov(fit)

# data frame for predictions
mfx_pred <- data.frame(mfx = rep(NA, 4), se = rep(NA, 4), 
    row.names = c("amf0", "amf1", "carbf0", "carbf1"))
disc <- rownames(mfx_pred)

# hard coded prediction estimates and SE  
disx0c <- disx1c <- disx0a <- disx1a <- x1 
disx1a[, "amf1"] <- max(x1[, "amf1"]) 
disx0a[, "amf1"] <- min(x1[, "amf1"]) 
disx1c[, "carbf1"] <- max(x1[, "carbf1"]) 
disx0c[, "carbf1"] <- min(x1[, "carbf1"])
mfx_pred["amf0", 1] <- mean(plogis(disx0a %*% be))
mfx_pred["amf1", 1] <- mean(plogis(disx1a %*% be))
mfx_pred["carbf0", 1] <- mean(plogis(disx0c %*% be))
mfx_pred["carbf1", 1] <- mean(plogis(disx1c %*% be))
# standard errors
gr0a <- as.numeric(dlogis(disx0a %*% be)) * disx0a
gr1a <- as.numeric(dlogis(disx1a %*% be)) * disx1a
gr0c <- as.numeric(dlogis(disx0c %*% be)) * disx0c
gr1c <- as.numeric(dlogis(disx1c %*% be)) * disx1c
avegr0a <- as.matrix(colMeans(gr0a))
avegr1a <- as.matrix(colMeans(gr1a))
avegr0c <- as.matrix(colMeans(gr0c))
avegr1c <- as.matrix(colMeans(gr1c))
mfx_pred["amf0", 2] <- sqrt(t(avegr0a) %*% vcv %*% avegr0a)
mfx_pred["amf1", 2] <- sqrt(t(avegr1a) %*% vcv %*% avegr1a)
mfx_pred["carbf0", 2] <- sqrt(t(avegr0c) %*% vcv %*% avegr0c)
mfx_pred["carbf1", 2] <- sqrt(t(avegr1c) %*% vcv %*% avegr1c)  

mfx_pred$pred <- rownames(mfx_pred)
    mfx_pred$lcl <- mfx_pred$mfx - (mfx_pred$se * 1.96)
mfx_pred$ucl <- mfx_pred$mfx + (mfx_pred$se * 1.96)

#          mfx    se   pred     lcl   ucl
# amf0   0.366 0.101   amf0  0.1682 0.563
# amf1   0.543 0.122   amf1  0.3041 0.782
# carbf0 0.601 0.107 carbf0  0.3916 0.811
# carbf1 0.165 0.105 carbf1 -0.0412 0.372

ggplot(mfx_pred, aes(x = pred, y = mfx)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl)) +
    theme_bw()
```

Comment: You might want to look up how to interpret CIs because the amount of overlap in the effects result you have does not demonstrate the effect is not significant. You also might want to look at the variety of possible binomial CIs on wikipedia. Your mfx_pred ones are *not* the same as the effects ones. You'll need to examine the effects package to see what it's doing.

Comment: Also, please don't post code that modifies a built in data object. Make a copy with a different name.

Comment: @John: thanks - I edited to create a new object with the `mtcars` dataset. I know that you can have some overlap in 95% CIs and still have significance. In fact, I think it's roughly an 84% CI that produces confidence regions that indicate significance with non-overlap. The `effects` results have a lot of overlap, however, and differ substantially from those I get when modifying the `mfx` code. It's unclear to me why.

Comment: @John: 84% CIs calculated using `effects` have no overlap, so I take your point, thanks. I'm unsure why the 95% CIs differ so much between the `effects` package and the modified `mfx` code (where they don't overlap). Based on the `effects` documentation, it seems that average marginal effects are calculated, just like in my `mfx` example. I'll try to look at the `effects` source code...

Comment: @John: I also take your point about binomial CIs. Though it's unclear to me how to calculate something like Jeffreys interval from the output of the model. I'll look into this.

Comment: Absolute risk difference is a function of all the covariate settings.  Trying to average unlikes is at the heart of the problem.